# how to monitor the node's state?

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the problem, I have several nodes running together ,and they should work well for a long time. But, I'm not sure wheather they will break or not . So,is there anything can be used to   monitor the state of the nodes ? if one broke up,it can show something or inform there are something wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264641/how-to-monitor-the-node%27s-state?/) by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could create [bonds](http://wiki.ros.org/bond).

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0